# In tensorflow distributed mode, there is something weird run in one ps - one worker

Tags: tensorflow, distributed-computing, distributed-system

I'm working on training some simple model(MNIST) for testing dsitributed mode with one parameter server and one worker server seperately.

However during training, it seems stop suddenly with no reason. When I checked the `MasterSession` class `Run()` method, there was something weird thing happens. As I know, there is variable `num_running_` which counts the active RunStep calls.

As I mentioned above, I trained with only one training server, so I thought that the value of `num_running_` should be 1 or 0. However the value become more than 1. And After the value become more than 1, the training do not perfom next step(iteration). I captured screenshot of that situation. I cannot understand why this things happened. Can I get some advice?

(This experiment was performed with 1 nvidia K80 gpu in worker server, 1 nvidia K80 gpu in ps server. I used Tensorflow r1.3)

[image]